# clear form using knockout

Tags: knockout-2.0

I am binding form fields value using knockout foreach binding which uses the value retrived from database & that  work fine. but how to use this foreach binding to clear same form which i binding through knockout foreach binding? how to achive this?

Comment: Can you post some example code in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that shows how you are binding to your form?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pattern described in this blog post: http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/01/simple-editor-pattern-knockout-js.html

```
var Item = function(data) {
    this.name = ko.observable();
    this.price = ko.observable();
    this.cache = function() {};

    this.update(data);
};

ko.utils.extend(Item.prototype, {
  update: function(data) {
    this.name(data.name || "new item");
    this.price(data.price || 0);

    //save off the latest data for later use
    this.cache.latestData = data;
  },
  revert: function() {
    this.update(this.cache.latestData);
  }
});
```

Now you can bind the cancel buttons click event to the `revert` method.

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.